# Spring JPA - CriteriaQuery for Composite key variables

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

### My scenario is, Inventory is root class and InventoryId is composite key class as defined below:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Inventory  implements java.io.Serializable {
    
    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 748080717136028484L;
    
    /** The id. */
    @Id
    private InventoryId id;
}
```

```java
@Data
@Embeddable
public class InventoryId implements java.io.Serializable {
    
    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6479717401762529315L;
    
    /** The product id. */
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String productId;

    /** The branch id. */
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String branchId;
}
```

Using the Criteria query as below:

@Override

```
public List<Inventory> getInventoryLevelsPerProduct(String productId,String branchId) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Inventory> cq = cb.createQuery(Inventory.class);

    Root<Inventory> root = cq.from(Inventory.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    InventoryId inventoryId  = new InventoryId();
           
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(productId)) {
        inventoryId.setProductId(productId);
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("id"), inventoryId ));
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(branchId)) {
        inventoryId.setBranchId(branchId);
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("id"), inventoryId));
    } 
    cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

---

If I pass productId and branchId it is returning the records. How to make this query workable when we pass one input search criteria?

Thanks in advance.